# VirtualBox, Host: Ubuntu 18.04, Guest: Windows 10, resizing screen

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have just installed Windows 10 in a VirtualBox VM using Ubuntu 18.04 as a host OS. 
I would like to resize the VM screen (in the VirtualBox window) so that it can fit the entire host's screen. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Right Ctrl + F shortcut for going full-screen? (perform the shortcut on the virtual machine while running it)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't fill the screen

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions and the extension pack (host)?

Comment: Well, I installed the guest additions and now it works. What exactly are the guest additions and the extension pack?

Comment: The extension pack enables additional hardware supported in the VMs, among others, USB3 and graphics stuff. The guest additions are a pack of drivers for the virtualized hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use your VM on full-screen mode (better resolution), you have to install the Guest Additions: Guest Additions are like the drivers for your VM which installs support for better USB technologies (USB 2.0, USB 3.0) and better graphics. First of all you need to download and install the Extension Pack, which enables you to use the Guest Additions. You can download the latest version of the Extension Pack (v6.0.6, to the time of writing this answer) [here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.6.vbox-extpack). If you're using a previous version of VirtualBox you can [choose your version here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds)

## Installation Steps

Power on your VM, then, head to the **Devices** menu and choose the "Insert Guest Additions CD Image..." option. 
[image: Installing Guest Additions]

It will be recognized on the VM; proceed to install the additions (Next, Next, Next, Install...) and accept the installation for the VirtualBox driver.
[image: Installation of the VirtualBox required drivers]

After the installation is complete, the installer will ask you to restart your VM. After the restart, is now possible to go fullscreen with better resolution for the VM.

[image: Guest Additions succesfully installed]

That's it.

Comment: I'm not getting that dialog where it asks to install the display driver. Any idea why that could be?